# XAML databinding not updating

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding

just need a little help with some databinding.

So I have an ObservableCollection of a custom object. The properties of the object are as shown:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Name
    /// </summary>
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }        

    /// <summary>
    /// Status
    /// </summary>
    private int _status;
    public int Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _status)
            {
                _status = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Visible information
    /// </summary>
    private Visibility _visible;
    public Visibility Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return _visible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _visible)
            {
                _visible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Visible");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And basically I have three TextBlocks, the first two of which have Text binded to Name and Status while the third has:

```
Visibility = {Binding Visible}
```

But whenever I want to toggle the visibility property, I can only toggle it from the Visible state to Collapsed, and then not again. My toggle looks like this:

```
            ItemViewModel l = ((sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem) as ItemViewModel;
            MessageBox.Show(l.Visible.ToString());
            if (l.Visible == Visibility.Collapsed)
                l.Visible = Visibility.Visible;
            else
                l.Visible = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Note: ItemViewModel is the custom class for the collection, ie.

```
ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
```

Obviously it's just a rough test, but still doesn't work. The messagebox is always showing "Visible" regardless of the real visibility state of the item. How can I get it to get the ***real*** value of Visibility?

If anyone has any idea, that would be great.

Thanks.

EDIT: Adding XAML for the Textblocks for clarity:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="20"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,280,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="t1" Text="Test for visibility" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Visibility="{Binding Visible}"/>
```

Keep in mind these textblocks are encased within a stackpanel and a longlistselector so simply changing t1.Visible is out of the question.

Comment: Can you post the entire XAML for the third textbox?

Comment: Added to the original post so it's more noticeable

Comment: Does your debug msgbox behave as you would expect?

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that your property *always* stays `Visible`?  So the problem [might be] in that your property is not changing, not that the binding is not working?

Comment: @MartinClarke No, it always shows "Visible" regardless of the actual state.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Maybe, but it seems to work. For example, one of the items has the third textblock visible, and toggling its value correctly hides the textblock, its just trying to toggle it back does nothing.

Comment: @Traw92 So you can set the `Visible` property to `Collapsed` and it does disappear, but the `MessageBox` still says it's `Visible`?  But you can never set it back to `Visible`?

Comment: @CodingGorilla That's correct

Comment: have you set your **DataContext** to your ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>

Comment: @SéddikLaraba DataContext = App.ViewModel in the constructor

Comment: @Traw92 Have you put a break point in the property setter to make sure the valid isn't being reverted from some other piece of code?

Comment: @CodingGorilla THANKS! That did it.. How silly of me, I had some other code changing the value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, after more investigation, ends up being that the property was being set by another branch of code.